# Perl: Need an LWP & HTTP::Request POST code that actually works

Tags: perl, post, httprequest, lwp

I have been scratching my head trying to get LWP and HTTP::Request to actually pass a POST parameter to a web server.  The web server can see the fact that the request was a POST transaction, but it is not picking up the passed parameters.  I have been searching all day on this and have tried different things and I have yet to find something that works.  (The web server is working, I am able to manually send post transactions and when running the whole script, I am getting '200' status but I am not seeing any posted elements.  Any help would be appreciated.  Tnx.

```
my $ua2 = LWP::UserAgent->new;
$ua2->agent("Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows 98)");
my $req2 = HTTP::Request->new(POST => "$url", [ frm-advSearch => 'frmadvSearch' ]);
$req2->content_type('text/html');
my $res2 = $ua2->request($req2);
$http_stat = substr($res2->status_line,0,3);
```

Comment: `substr($res2->status_line,0,3)` is better written as `$res2->code`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
my $res = $ua->post($url,
   Content => [
      'frm-advSearch' => 'frmadvSearch',
   ],
);
```

which is short for

```
use HTTP::Request::Common qw( POST );

my $req = POST($url,
   Content => [
      'frm-advSearch' => 'frmadvSearch',
   ],
);

my $res = $ua->request($req);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a [Mojo::UserAgent](https://mojolicious.org/perldoc/Mojo/UserAgent) example, which I find easier to debug:

```
use Mojo::UserAgent;
my $ua = Mojo::UserAgent->new;
$ua->transactor->name( 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows 98)' );

my $url = 'http://www.example.com/form/';
my $tx = $ua->post( $url, form => { 'frm-advSearch' => 'frmadvSearch' } );
say $tx->req->to_string;
```

The transaction in `$tx` knows about the request so I can look at that:

```
POST /form/ HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows 98)
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Host: www.example.com
Content-Length: 26

frm-advSearch=frmadvSearch
```

Comment: Re "*which I find easier to debug*", `say $tx->req->to_string;` is not really easier than `say $req2->to_string;` or `say $tx->request->to_string;`

Comment: I find it easier. You may not.

Comment: Oh I agree. Typing 4 fewer chars is easier.